# Dropdown list in excel using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, libreoffice-calc

Is it possible to generate drop-down list using a formula in excel ?

I know it can be done using `Data-validation` but I don't want to use it.

For example:
I have `1, 2, 3, 4` in `A1-A4`,In cell B1 I will use a formula, which will render a dropdown list with entries containing `1, 2, 3 and 4`.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Data-validation is the only way to create drop down in Excel. While using the data-validation, either you can use formula directly or using a named range.

Answer (score 0):

I have done quite the same. The idea is to create a NAMED range (that would contain the values you want to show in the list) and use the name of the range in the data validation definition, something like:

1. Set the value of "Allow" to list,
2. Set the value of "Source" to =My_Named_Range

That should do. You can also se explicit range definition (e.g. B4:b88) if this range is static.

Comment: Using data validation is explicitly out of the question.

Comment: I can't use `Data Validation` @FDavidov  Any other ways other than this ? (Only using formulas) ?

Comment: Sorry, but not that I know of. If I may ask, why is data validation not an option?